# Conditions for EC261 compensation

Tags: legal, eu, compensation

The condition to receive flight compensation via EC261 are:

the person has:

- a confirmed reservation on the flight, and
  arrived in time for check-in as indicated on the ticket or communication from the airline, or, if no time is so indicated, no less than 45 minutes prior to the scheduled departure time of the flight
  OR
- have been transferred from the flight for which he/she held a reservation to some other flight

In addition, if the delay is more than 5 hours, the passenger has a right to forfeit the flight and receive the ticket price back.

Does it mean that if the airline notifies about a long delay and passenger cancels the ticket, he still has to arrive in time for check-in to receive cash compensation?